# Query SAP HANA tables from ADX

Tags: hana, azure-data-explorer, adx

We have a requirement to query SAP HANA table via ADX, is there a possibility or approach to achieve this requirement.

Currently we are using ADF route to pull data from SAP HANA and then to ADX. So would like to explore direct way to querying the data.

Comment: I believe using ADF is the only way for now

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This capability does not exist, please submit this ask at the http://aka.ms/kustouservoice

Comment: Thanks for your response.